# GitHub Action to auto update Go import paths

Tags: bash, go, scripting, github-actions

Is there a GitHub action to auto-open a PR with Go import paths updated to a new major version?

For example, my module is `module github.com/org/example/v1`

and imports across the repo are `import "github.com/org/example/v1/test"`.

I would like to run an action that will open a PR with all imports + the module updated to `v2` like:

```
`import "github.com/org/example/v2/test"`
```

Is there one like that?

If not, does anyone have a bash script for doing this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Major version change assumes that the package has breaking changes. Simply bumping the version number can make code not compilable. Go designers made it complicated on purpose.

Comment: I understand. We are adding extra safeguards and policies for detecting breaking changes. The goal is to make the workflow automated to ease maintenance when the breaking change has been decided on as acceptable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote some custom logic for this: https://github.com/osmosis-labs/osmosis/pull/2094

Basically, it has a bash script that goes over all files and increases the major version.

A custom GA workflow then runs the script from a new branch and opens a pull request against the target branch.